# What is the cheapest way to send funds from Sweden to Switzerland?

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer, wire-transfer

I need to make a payment of about 6200 CHF to a Swiss bank account. My money is in SEK in a Swedish bank account.

Would it be preferable to use Transferwise / something similar to it, or should I send it like I would send money to some other Swedish bank?

Could SEPA style transactions be used for such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send money to some other Swedish bank, they're likely to take some fees and/or give an exchange rate worse than the interbank exchange rate. Transferwise takes [0.35% Fee + kr 18.00 SEK](https://transferwise.com/pricing/sek-to-chf#/pricing-page-calculator-anchor).

[Revolut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolut) uses the [interbank exchange rate for CHF <-> SEK on weekdays (Mon-Fri UTC)](https://www.revolut.com/en-FR/help/getting-started/exchanging-currencies/what-foreign-exchange-rate-will-i-get) and don't have any [fee](https://www.revolut.com/en-FR/legal/fees), so that's the cheapest option I am aware of. They do have a [limit of 6,000 CHF / month](https://www.revolut.com/en-FR/legal/fees) (reset on the 12th midnight CET of each month), above which they'll take a 0.5% conversion fee (unless you  purchase the premium/metal accounts, in which case there is no limit). If you're interested in trying out Revolut, you can use the https://revolut.com/r/franck2q2 referral link to get a free physical debit card.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have Revolut already and a physical visa card as well (not premium). I forgot about this, good point. Just a question, the 0.5% conversion fee will be calculated then on the whole sum ie 6200 CHF, or on the remaining 200 CHF?

Comment: @Dsxp  remaining 200 CHF if you do 1 conversion of 6000 CHF and 1 conversion of CHF. Pretty sure that'd be the same with 1 conversion of 6200 CHF but I haven't tried.